# admin generator yaml: link to another module

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

How can I generate link to another module in Symfony admin generator Yaml?
I am trying to link from sfGuardUser module (user list) to profile/viewProfilesDetails but it always points to sfGuardUser/viewProfilesDetails

My generator.yml :

```
(...)
  list:
    title:   Użytkownicy
    display: [=username, _name, created_at, last_login]
    actions: {}
    batch_actions: {}
    object_actions:
      _edit: ~
      signIn:
        label:  Zaloguj jako
        action: signIn
      viewProfiles:
        label:  Profile
        module: profiles
        action: viewProfilesDetails
(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can specify a module in this configuration, but only an action from the same module.

I personnaly do this in this way.

`generator.yml` :

```
object_actions:
  _edit: ~
  _delete: ~
  viewItems: { label: View items, action: viewItems }
```

Then in the same module for the `generator.yml`, I create an action:

```
public function executeViewItems($request)
{
  $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('items'));
}
```

It generates a link called *View items*, like `/blog/158/viewItems` which redirect to the `/items` (which is the route `@items`).

**Edit:**

In fact, you **can't** specify an other module.

The template [`_list_td_actions.php`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/data/generator/sfDoctrineModule/admin/template/templates/_list_td_actions.php) display `list.object_actions`. Here is the interesting part:

```
<?php else: ?>
    <li class="sf_admin_action_<?php echo $params['class_suffix'] ?>">
      <?php echo $this->addCredentialCondition($this->getLinkToAction($name, $params, true), $params) ?>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It calls the `getLinkToAction` which use the current module by using `$this->getModuleName()`:

```
return '[?php echo link_to(
  __(\''.$params['label'].'\', array(), \''.$this->getI18nCatalogue().'\'), 
  \''.$this->getModuleName().'/'.$action.$url_params.', 
  '.$this->asPhp($params['params']).'
) ?]';
```

Comment: It looks like acceptable work-around, but I find it very strange that you can't link to another module directly...